# PHP difference function doesn't format hours and seconds with leading zero

Tags: php, datetime, difference

## What I have:

Two times, the difference of which I'm calculating using `diff()`:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('03:15:57');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('02:14:51');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
//Output: 01:1:6
```

## What I need:

I need the hours, minutes and seconds to all have a leading zero.

## What I've tried:

I've capitalised "i" and "s":

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('03:15:57');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('02:14:51');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
//Output: 01:01:06
```

## My question:

Why isn't H:i:s outputting with leading zeros?

Why does my solution work? [According to the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), "S" means...

> English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters.

...and "I" isn't defined.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php your looking at the wrong manual page

Comment: `Why isn't H:i:s outputting with leading zeros?` Because it does not and it's reflected in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php Please, read manual first.

Comment: @smith Thank you. I thought `$interval` was an arbitrary valuable name. I didn't realise it was behaving as a predefined function.